# Java String to byte[] (String contains object data)

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I am using a JavaScript to Applet object called JSObject and I get from my JSObject the value of a java object that I stored in my html page.

The java object is a byte[] but JavaScript converts it to a String.

So in the HTML page: object value = `[B@ca0b6`

In the Applet, the String value is also `[B@ca0b6`

Is there a way for me to convert this String value of `[B@ca0b6` into the byte representation?
I don't mean `String.getByte()` because that will convert the STRING `[B@ca0b6` into `byte[]` data.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no objects in HTML. Do you mean the object you saved in JS?

Comment: Yes, I've updated this answer to something more understandable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566346/getting-a-javaobject-out-of-a-jsobject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. This is the default `toString()` method, which does not output anything of the array contents. It contains only the type of the object (array of bytes) and the memory address within the JVM, in hex.

If you want to convert your array to `String` properly, use `Arrays.toString(array)`

Comment: Interesting, I'll need to find a different approach.  Thanks!

Comment: I've created a new question to try to solve this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566346/getting-a-javaobject-out-of-a-jsobject  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
new String(bytearray, "UTF-8")
```

(change `UTF-8` to something else (e.g., `ISO-8859-1`) if your bytes are not UTF-8.)

Comment: I think he doesn't want this.

Comment: @Bozho: It's too bad the question isn't more explicit in what the OP wants. :-( Both your answer and mine are correct, depending on how the question is interpreted.

Comment: I assumed the "string" interferes not because it consists of the bytes, but because it is outputted as a string in html