# Getting a JavaObject out of a JSObject

Tags: java, javascript, html, xhtml, applet

I have a Javascript function in my xhtml page that does the following:

HTML FILE:

```
function getData(){
   var data = document.getElementById('data');
   return data;        
}

<input type="hidden" value="#{bean.bytes}"/>
```

Backing Bean Code:

```
public class Bean{
    public byte[] getBytes(){
       return this.bytes;
    }
}
```

And I have an applet that needs to get this byte array from the html
Applet code:

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet{
   JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
   JSObject returnedValue = win.call("getData", null);
}
```

I've been trying to call the returnedValue.getMember("value") *(fixed)*; but that gets a null value.
I also tried to change the javascript to this:

HTML:

```
function getData(){
   var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
   return data;        
}
```

But that will only return me the String representation of the byte[], not the actual object.

**So my question is: 
How do I use JSObject to get a JavaObject?**

*Current method gets me back a String*

Answer (score 0):

There is no `data` property.
Change it to `returnedValue.getMember("value")`.

Comment: It looks like using returnedValue.getMember("value") gives me back a String :(

Comment: @Vedar: That's because it _is_ a string.  What were you expecting?

Comment: well since the Bean returned a byte[] I was expecting a byte[] back.

Comment: The HTML DOM element's `value` property is a string, not a `byte[]`.